# What does "Roguish" exactlly mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I have searched a lot of dictionaries but still I can't understand the exact meaning of ***roguish*** in the text below.

> "Ah, that's so, that's so!" Louisa said. "And what was it in my case
> but vanity, which deserves to get slapped down!" Her eyes were glassy
> and her expression ***roguish***. "You don't think he'd had a good look at
> me any one time and thought the original was even worse than that poor
> picture, so he backed off?"
>
> <sub>"casting away" by Alice Munro</sub>

Please tell me, What kind of a look is the writer trying to depict with ***"...and her expression roguish"***?

Comment: I believe that this *roguish* can be read as *kind of rouge*. I didn't read the book so I'm not sure which sense of *rouge* should be used, but mainly it means either dishonest, unpredictable, or defective.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You want "rogue" there, not "rouge". Rouge is the French word for "red" and also used in English as another word for lipstick.

Comment: Thank you Abby and Damkerng. I think "unpredictable" doesn't fit there. She has been betrayed and also she is drunk so I think it could be either "defective" or "dishonest".

Comment: I am not sure about "dishonest" either because she is telling the truth and also she is the victim, so why would the writer mean that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a [rogue](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rogue). We'd need more context to know for sure, but the intent seems to be either "immoral" or "causing mischief." Glassy eyes suggests the speaker is drunk or on drugs?

Comment: Thank you, I think both of your suggestions are good. By the way would you please tell me if this is a common word nowadays?

Comment: @GATA It is still in use, though not as much to refer to people. Think of the term "rogue state" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_state )  A common pickpocket or mugger would not be referred to as a rogue in the 21st century.

Comment: @relaxing Could you put the definitions in your answer? Because links don't last forever!

Comment: A rogue is a free thinking mischief maker, (s)he's charming, I wouldn't think of the word "immoral". Think Han Solo.

Comment: Han Solo had his immoral moments -- smuggling suspicious packages for a gangster, concerned only with monetary reward for rescuing the princess. (He later redeems himself, yes.)